# jquery not loading in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have recently started web development.  As I have been trying to make pages with jQuery on them, I have been having a bunch of trouble.  The code I write and link to from my HTML page won't load, and when I look at the console in a browser, it doesn't show any scripts being loaded.  The only way I can get them to load is by wrapping my code in `<script>` tags in the HTML document itself, and then it works fine.  I have tried using `<script src="source.js">` in the `<head>` tags, as well as before the closing `<body>` tag but nothing happens.  The .css file loads and aside from the Javascript, the website works fine.  If you see anything else I am doing wrong, such as formatting the code itself, or using bad style, please point that out as well.  As I am trying to get going as a developer, any help you could give would be much appreciated.  Here are the files for one of the many sites I have trouble with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dot_grid.css">
    <script src="dot_grid.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <br>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <br>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <br>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <br>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <br>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <br>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <br>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <br>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <br>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="reset">RESET</div>
    <div id="opac">Change opacity</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

All those `<div>` tags are making the grid... if there's a better way, by all means, let me know :P

CSS:

```
div div{
    height:25px;
    width:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:100%;
    background:orange;
    position:static;
    border:none;
}
.other1 {
    background:teal;
}
#addRow {
    height:25px;
    width:35px;
    background:#334477;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;

}
#reset {
    height:1em;
    width:3.25em;
    font-size:1em;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:5px;
    opacity:0.3;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#reset:hover {
    color:black;
    background:#666600;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#opac {
    height:1em;
    width:6.5em;
    font-size:1em;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    opacity:0.3;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#opac:hover {
    color:black;
    background:#666600;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

...and the jQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div div").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("background","red");
    });
    $("div div").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("background","orange");
    });
    $(".other1").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("background","blue");
    });
    $(".other1").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("background","teal");
    });
    $("div div").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow",0);
    });
    $("#reset").click(function(){
        $("div div").fadeTo("slow",1);
    });
    $("#reset").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("fast",1);
    });
    $("#reset").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("fast",0.3);
    });
    $("#opac").click(function(){
        $("div div").fadeTo("slow",Math.random());
    });
    $("#opac").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("fast",1);
    });
    $("#opac").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("fast",0.3);
    });
});
```

I'm sorry the files are so long, but again, if you could help me, that would be great.

Comment: Your page does not include jQuery.

Comment: Add this in you head tag: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Is it really that simple?  It will work if I just add that?

Comment: @user2570483: Well, it *might* work after that.  The first problem is that jQuery isn't loaded.  There could potentially be more problems...

Comment: Okay, I still can't get it to do anything.  Does that go anywhere specific in the head tag?  Should I move the link to my script to the end of the body?

Comment: For future reference, I would familiar myself with your browsers built in javascript debugger.  A quick look at the log messages output by your debugger would have immediately told you that your script code was attempted but all of those jquery commands were undefined.  Your script would have bailed out early, hence no javascript code was doing anything.

Comment: @user2570483, http://jsbin.com/iqovay/1/edit, not sure what is your intention, but now it works... just copy code from jsbin...

Comment: @Lochemage I did that, but I didn't know what it meant.  Fortunately, now I do, and I have fixed the problem.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the jQuery library in your file.
Try this for head tag, and let us know if you found more problems.

```
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dot_grid.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dot_grid.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
```

You can also download it [**here**](http://jquery.com/download/), put it in your `.js` directory and add it like you did with your `dot_grid.js`

Comment: Well, I copied what you wrote and pasted it over the head tag in my .html file and it still doesn't load :(

Comment: @user2570483, check this by "nevermind" (http://jsbin.com/iqovay/1/edit), is this what you want? Do you test it on your computer or on a web server?

Comment: Yes!  That's how it's supposed to work, I just don't want to put all the jQuery in the .html file.  I have the files saved on my flash drive, and I test it by opening the html in a web browser.  Am I supposed to do something else?  My files aren't hosted anywhere, they're just local.

Comment: @user2570483, do you have internet on your computer to load the goolge hosted jQuery file?? Also wrap your jQuery code in `$(function(){ ...your code... });`

Comment: I do have internet... I thought the jQuery was supposed to be in the `$(document).ready(...code...);` but okay, it seems like you are a bit better at this than I am :P

Comment: @user2570483, yeah, ok you had `.ready already`. It should work both ways.

Comment: Yeah, I can try "inspect element" in chrome, and it doesn't seem like either script is loading (at least, they have little stop signs next to them...) it says "uncaught reference error: $ is not defined" about my code

Comment: @user2570483, that error often shows up when jQuery didn't load... Check in chrome's console in the resources > scripts if jQuery is there.

Comment: So, the only script it shows is mine, and right after `$(document).ready` it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".  It doesn't show the google script.  Maybe it's because I don't have it downloaded?  Is it looking for it in my flash drive?

Comment: @user2570483, ok. Go >[here](http://jquery.com/download/)< and download it and run it from your machine. Like you did on your script.

Comment: Yeah, I saved the uncompressed one as a .js file, changed the link in my html and it didn't work, so I tried it as a .txt file and (probably obviously) that didn't do anything either.  Sorry for the trouble :(

Comment: @user2570483, sorry to hear. I suggest you try it online. If the code you posted here is all your code, then it works as you saw by "neverminds" jbin example. Check the console again. Console is your friend :)

Comment: What do you mean online?  That I should host it somewhere?  Again, I'm pretty new to this :P  Where can I go to do that?

Comment: @user2570483, check your console again in resources > scripts with jQuery loaded from your harddrive. It should work there.

Comment: Yeah... do you happen to know the full URL for the google api?  The jQuery file still isn't showing up.  Oh, actually, is the file supposed to download automatically from the jQuery site you gave me?  It just shows up as a bunch of text.

Comment: AAH it feels like it's so close!  I got the jQuery file to download, and it shows in the console now, but it's throwing another error, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" This is driving me crazy! ...and probably you too.

Comment: AUGH that was so stupid!  You helped a bunch, thanks.  The end was my fault for not downloading and linking it right, but I got it fixed and it works just fine now.  You have saved me from losing my mind.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2570483, good morning. I live in Europe so bed time came, sorry :) I'm glad I could help. Post more questions if you run into trouble, people are always looking for problems to solve :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the jQuery library to use it.
Add this 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` after 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="dot_grid.css">`

Comment: Why such an old version of jQuery? 1.7.2 is ancient.

Comment: @SrikanthAD: You might want to find a new script source, then.